# What format is the Dump File in SoapUI?

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, mtom, xop

I make a request to a Web-Service to download a file as an MTOM/XOP attachment; The file is an Excel file.xlsx;
The response in the SoapUI tool comes back 200-OK, with typical soap-envelope, and the attachment is there in the SOAP-UI grid, and I can export the attachment from the SOAP-UI grid to a file, and it verifies ok (it is my original Excel file).

The real question is the Dump file that got created is some garbled binary file, and I got no idea what its contents are, what format it is in, whether it includes both the soap xml response and attachment, but more importantly how can I decode it to be useful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer, rather than deleting the question, I'll leave it up here in case anyone else struggles with this as I did !

In the Raw response of SOAP-UI, we can see "Content-Encoding: gzip"; this is dependent on the config of the web-service / web-server.

So after decoding the Dump File with GZipStream (I used C#), I got an intelligible format, whereupon I can see the original Excel file embedded in there !

Comment: Leaving this here for someone in the future - On a related note, the dump file can be unzipped with something like 7zip to get the response file if needed.